# Изображение в Джанго

Tags: python, html, django

Как отобразить на странице в браузере изображение, делал все как написано(почти) - не работет
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Модель

```
class Bike(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='image/bike/%Y/%M/%D')
content = models.TextField()
brand = models.ForeignKey('Brand', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
issue_date= models.DateField()
```

Вью

```
class BikeListView(ListView):
paginate_by = 2
model = Bike
template_name = 'home/bikes.html'  
context_object_name = 'bikes'
```

urls

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('home.urls')),
   ]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Настройки

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = []
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Шаблон

```
{% for bike in bikes %}
<li>
<a href="{{ bike.pk }}">{{ bike.title }}</a>
<img src="{{ bike.image.url }}" alt="Photo">
<p>{{ bike.content }}</p>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Не работает что? Не работает где? Что происходит вместо работы?

Comment: Смотрели какая получается ссылка в html-коде? Что будет если её открыть в отдельной вкладке?

Comment: <img src="/media/image/bike/2023/10/01/02/23/format.jpg" alt="Photo">

Comment: Если открыть как ссылку пишет путь не существует

Comment: @bub Сайт запускается на сервере у провайдера или со своего компьютера? Установлено  в setings.py DEBUG = True или DEBUG = False?

Comment: false, со своего компа

Comment: @bub  Установите True

Answer (score 0):

фотографии должны быть в папке static (название приложения/static/название приложения/img/твое фото)

что бы его вывести ,ты в html пишешь

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="{% static 'название твоего приложения/img/название фотографии' %}" alt="">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Фотографии, загружаемые пользователем, должны быть не в static, а в media